# Taylor series expansion of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ about a point $a \in \Bbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

> How to find the Taylor series expansion of $$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$ about a point $a \in \Bbb{R}$ ?

I know it has the form $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-a)^n$$ where $a_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}$.

So in order to find that expression, we find all derivatives of $f$ and then use $a_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}$

But finding all derivative of $f$ is a difficult task.

Is there any other way to show this?

What I'm misunderstanding the given $a_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}$ method (if any) ?

Comment: I am confused. Do you really want it around an arbitrary point $a$? Or just around $0$?

Comment: I want that expression about an arbitrary point $a \in \Bbb{R}$

Comment: Then you should have written$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-a)^n.$$

Comment: Oh sorry! I edit my question

Comment: Related: [Finding the $100$th derivative of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ without using complex numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2937547).

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite
$$
\frac{1}{(t+a)^2+1)}=\frac{A}{t+a+i}+\frac{B}{t+a-i}
$$
whence
$$
A=\frac{i}{2},\qquad B=-\frac{i}{2}.
$$
Now expand in power series around $t=0$
$$
\frac{1}{t+a+i}=\frac{1}{a+i}\frac{1}{1+\dfrac{t}{a+i}}
$$
and do the same for the other fraction.

Sum up and set $t=x-a$.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of the function 
$$f=\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$$
can be written as:
$$f^{(k)}(x)=-i\dfrac{1}{2}pochhammer(-k,k)(x-i)^{(-1-k)}+i\dfrac{1}{2}pochhammer(-k,k)(x+i)^{(-1-k)}$$
where the function 'pochhammer(a,b)' is defined as:
$$pochhammer(z,a)=\dfrac{\Gamma(z+a)}{\Gamma(z)}$$